# Why are adults so suceptible to dizziness?

Tags: development, human-physiology, balance

I have a child and she, like pretty much all the others it seems, loves spinny rides in the park. Adults often can't stand them.

In fact, I recall going from loving to hating dizziness over the space of about 3 years, at about the beginning of puberty.

Why do adults react more badly to dizziness than children?

Comment: Do you have any data to support your assertion "adults react more badly to dizziness than children" ? Because that could be just your own experience, not a general fact per se.

Comment: @alec_djinn Well, I know this isn't exactly what you were going for, but when you think about it, if you ask most adults, they'll tell you they don't really _like_ being dizzy.

Comment: I found quite opposite: when I was kid, I was probably more sensitive to dizziness on rotation, and vomited easily. But in adult-age I'm much less sensitive to dizziness in rotation, and doesn't vomit in that so easily. but seemingly the direct amount of dizziness is probably as same as childhood.

Comment: Maybe than adults the childrens are less worried about dizzy feeling (and more enthusiastic to rounding rides)... so maybe they report it a less. Also; maybe kids habituated in it for daily basis got desensitized... like professional *Katthak* dancers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathak)